# How to add JS event on JSON success with each

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

My `Code-igniter` view has `AJAX` data as follows. `DIV` `article-data` contents list of `DIVs`.(working perfect) Now i want to each DIV as a button and where i put button click event. Where i put following code.

```
$(".target").click(function () {

});
```

JS

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>' + 'main/data',
    dataType: "JSON",
    type: "POST",
    success: function(retdata) {
      $.each(retdata, function(i) {
        var content = '<div class="target btn-default">' + retdata[i].content + '</div>';
        $(".article-data").append(content);  //line 23

      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="article-data">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach, when generating elements dynamically. You don't need to bind event in `success` block.

> The delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, we can use delegated events to bind the click event to dynamically created elements and also to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers.

*General Syntax*

```
$(document).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

In place of `document` you should use closest static container.

*Example*

```
$(function() {
  $(".article-data").on('click', ".target", function() {
    //Your code
  });
})
```

```js
$(function() {
  $(".article-data").on('click', ".target", function() {
    //Your code
  });
})


$(window).load(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>' + 'main/data',
    dataType: "JSON",
    type: "POST",
    success: function(retdata) {
      $.each(retdata, function(i) {
        var content = '<div class="target btn-default">' + retdata[i].content + '</div>';
        $(".article-data").append(content); //line 23

      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="article-data">

</div>
```

A good read [Direct and delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)

Comment: click event is working. perfect answer. @Satpal it is only for click event? I used it for mouse hover which is not working. `$(".article-data").on('hover', ".target", function() {}`

Comment: @GeethWelagedara, `.hover()` is a short-hand for `$( selector ).mouseenter( handlerIn ).mouseleave( handlerOut );`, You should use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` event as there is no event as `hover`

Answer (score 1):

Just use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). It will bind the event to items added to DOM even after the document is ready.

```
$(document).on('click', ".target", function () {

});
```